# Fineract Spring Boot Application Deployment Issue on AWS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, apache-fineract

I'm facing a problem while deploying my Fineract Spring Boot application on an AWS server (Ubuntu amd Tx large). The application is based on the develop branch of the Fineract repository, and I've followed the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/apache/fineract/tree/develop).

Here are the key steps I've taken:

Modified application.properties and build.gradle as per the configuration requirements.
Set up a PostgreSQL database on AWS RDS and ensured that the database connection details in application.properties are accurate.

Ran the following Gradle commands:

```
<code>
./gradlew createPGDB -PdbName=fineract_tenants
./gradlew createPGDB -PdbName=fineract_default
./gradlew bootRun
</code>
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the server stops responding after running ./gradlew bootRun

I've checked logs, resource usage, security group settings, and Nginx configuration, but I can't seem to pinpoint the exact problem. The logs do not show any error messages or exceptions.

./gradlew build runs successfully.

Has anyone successfully deployed the develop branch of Fineract on AWS, or does anyone have insights into what might be causing this issue?

Any assistance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Environment Details:

AWS Server: Ubuntu amd Tx large
Fineract Branch: develop
Database: PostgreSQL on AWS RDS
Reverse Proxy: Nginx`

Comment: when you say "server stops responding" when you request end point **/fineract-provider/actuator/health** what do you get 404 500 204 timeout , connection refused ?